# Missing information with xpathSApply in the XML package in R

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

Using `htmlParse` and `xpathSApply` in the `XML package` in `R`, I've encountered an issue where I cannot download the `xmlValue` from a certain HTML element on a webpage. I'm fairly (if not entirely) new to using `R` for web scraping, so I'm not sure what I need to do in order to get the information I need.

Essentially the part of the code from the page I'm targeting reads:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div id="primarycitation">
<h4>Tetracycline Repressor Allostery Does not Depend on Divalent Metal Recognition.
</h4>
```

So after establishing the link to the webpage (in a `for`-loop; hence the `i`)**:

```
pdbId <- strtrim(pp2[i, 1], 4)
url2 <- paste("http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=", pdbId, sep = "")

val <- htmlParse(url2)
body <- xmlChildren(xmlRoot(val))$body
```

I've used:

```
script2 <- xpathSApply(body,
                       "//div[@id = 'primarycitation']",
                       xmlValue)
```

But all I get from that is junk:

```
> script2
[1] "\n            \n        "
```

Again, I'm not very familiar with web scraping, but to the best of my knowledge, and from the experience I've had so far with all my other functions, the citation title should be the value pulled by `xpathSApply`. Any suggestions?

** To tack it on at the end the `pdbId` I'm using here is `4D7N`.

Comment: I think you can just go down to `//div/h4` with your xpath

Comment: I've done this and it returns `list()` (that is, `List of 0`)

Comment: If `x` is the html, then this is what I got: `xpathSApply(htmlParse(x), "//div/h4", xmlValue, trim = TRUE) ## [1] "Tetracycline Repressor Allostery Does not Depend on Divalent Metal Recognition."`

Comment: Interesting, I went back and double-checked that my value `body` then had the information, but it looks like it only had `<div class="panel-body">
        <div id="primarycitation">
            
        </div>
    </div>`. Maybe there's something wrong with how I used `htmlParse` on the webpage?

Comment: The information is coming from a JS XHR request for http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/primaryArticle.do?structureId=4D7N hence why that div is empty in a "standard" parse. It's always a good idea to check for XHR requests when there's a difference between what's displayed and what's programmatically parsed.

Comment: @hrbrmstr How would you typically go about checking for XHR requests and correctly parsing information from there?

Comment: Browser Developer Tools. I use Chrome, but Safari & Firefox both have them. Also [burp proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/download.html) is also an option.